# Invalid resource error after following the azure AD angularJS to dotnet web api guide (description:AADSTS500011)

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have been following after this guide step by step:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi

The only thing that I didn't do (not sure if its related) is the following line:

"Also in the ToGoAPI project, open the file Controllers/ToGoListController.cs. In the [EnableCors...] attribute, enter the location of the To Do SPA client. By default it is https://localhost:44326. Make sure to omit the trailing slash.
"

The reason I didn't do it is simply because I can't find any [EnableCors...] in the code. I did try to enable CORS in a different way though. following this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors

Anyway, I get the following error:

"Error :invalid_resource
adal.js:973 Error description:AADSTS500011: The resource principal named https://yorecisraportsco.onmicrosoft.com/ToGoAPI was not found in the tenant named yorecisraportsco.onmicrosoft.com. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.
Trace ID: 64213edc-4b12-4caa-aa4e-b9ec82bd3000
Correlation ID: 607d25c1-d915-46eb-ba48-67adb70ddab8
Timestamp: 2019-03-04 12:41:33Z"

I am not sure why this is happning as I followed the guide - configured everything in Azure like it said and also configured it in the code.

Comment: Few things to check **1)** guide you refer to doesn't talk about multi-tenant app,  but did you mark any of the app registrations as multi-tenant? **2)** make sure you're signing in as a user from tenant *yorecisraportsco.onmicrosoft.com*, also a microsoft account like xyz@live.com or hotmail.com etc. won't work for this sample **3)** Make sure the app id URI for your ToGoAPI app registration exactly matches the value shown in error message `https://yorecisraportsco.onmicrosoft.com/ToGoAPI` You can check from Azure portal > AzureAD > App Registrations > ToGoAPI's app registration > Properties

Comment: @RohitSaigal Damn, I confused the app id URI with the Replay URL for some reason. so it was 3) Thanks! But, now I have a CORS error! Going back to my original message, I stated that the guide says something about EnableCors attribute but I can't seem to find it! the program went through some changes or I am not looking in the right place?

Comment: yes the sample seems to have changed since the original documentation. Look at the history for changes here.. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi/commit/7cd09e0f60c937efeaa3269299a9dfa405634fde#diff-8474735e15e9e584164bec7700d26ef3 it does add `app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);` which should allow all origins and HTTP methods.. read a related blog here - https://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-webapi-cors

Comment: Ok, so what I did was re inserting the config.enableCors() andthe [EnableCors...] but I see that it is not needed and basically the CORS part is now being taking care of in the sample (in the related blog the all of the steps are already fulfilled) yet I still get the CORS error: "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44327/api/ToGoList' from origin 'https://localhost:44326' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: Yes, I meant the same when I said that the new code does add `app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);` so it should be taken care of. I do see one relevant section in the blog https://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-webapi-cors at the very end *Don't forget to allow OPTIONS* which may help your case, as the error you get mentions preflight request doesn't pass access control check.

Comment: Yeah thought so too but the sample has those lines in the web.config under <handlers> as well

Comment: Anyway, I won't waste your time on that, I did this to test your advice on my following thread at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54927098/getting-a-valid-bearer-token-for-an-app-from-a-an-angular-ad-client/54929097#54929097 where I eventually went for option 1 and everything works (no need for CORS when you replace the ToGoAPI with the Blockchain API)

Comment: ok that makes sense. Option 1 is much simpler. I do think even here you're running into some configuration issues, because concepts stay the same.